# The supreme of a metric family is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\left\lbrace d_{\alpha} \right\rbrace_{\alpha \ in I}$ a family of metrics for $M \neq \emptyset $. Actually the relationship $d_{s}(x, y)=\sup_{\alpha \in I}\left\lbrace d_{\alpha} (x, y)\right\rbrace $ is a metric for $M$?, I noticed that the triangular inequality can be satisfied such that
$$\sup_{\alpha \in I}\left\lbrace d_{\alpha}(x, y) \right\rbrace  \leq \sup_{\alpha \in I}\left\lbrace d_{\alpha}(x, z)+d_{\alpha}(z, y) \right\rbrace \leq \sup_{\alpha \in I}\left\lbrace d_{\alpha}(x, z)\right\rbrace + \sup_{\alpha \in I}\left\lbrace d_{\alpha}(z, y) \right\rbrace$$

This using properties of the supremum and the fact that this family contains metrics, so we can get that the triangular inequality is satisfied; but it really satisfies the other properties? above all I doubt about the symmetry. Is it really a metric? and for the minimum is it also a metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a metric: if $x,y \in M$, then $d_s(x,y) = 0$ implies that $$\sup_{a \in I} d_a(x,y) = 0,$$ but since all the elements of this set are non-negative, this implies that every element has a value of $0$, which implies that $x = y$ since the elements are metrics applied to the points in question.

On the other hand, if $x = y$, then $$d_s(x,y) = \sup_{a \in I} d_a(x,y) = \sup_{a \in I} 0 = 0.$$

Furthermore, $$d_s(x,y) = \sup_{a \in I} d_a(x,y) = \sup_{a \in I} d_a(y,x) = d_s(y,x).$$

**EDIT:** note that if we assume that metrics need to be finite, then this function is indeed not a metric. Take in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the euclidian metric $d(x,y)$ and, for each $\lambda > 0$, the metric $d_\lambda(x,y) = \lambda d(x,y)$. Note that $$d_s(0, 1) = \sup_{\lambda > 0} d_\lambda(1,0) = \sup_{\lambda > 0} \lambda = \infty.$$

Comment: Technically, one needs to check that the supremum is always finite.

Comment: Oh, I don't usually assume metrics are finite, haha. But sure, I'll try to do it and post it here,

Comment: Instead of "is indeed not a metric", I would have said "might not be a metric": there are examples where the supremum is a (finite) metric!